# c# Linq Get the ids of list elements in the entity query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Can i find an entity in a single query and attract the ids in this list?

Entities

```
public class Blog : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
}

public class Category : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } = new List<Blog>();
}
```

Can I make the following code in one query? It should be find both blog and category ids.

```
var blog = _blogService.Queryable().Include(x => x.Categories).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
_blogService.DisposeContext();

var categoryIds = blog?.Categories.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `Queryable()` is `Queryable<Blog>`, you should be able to use the following:

```
_blogService
    .Queryable()
    .Include(x => x.Categories)
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Select(x => x.Categories.Select(c => c.Id))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

_blogService.Blogs.Where(b => b.Id == blogId).Include(b => b.Categories) should do the trick. No need to call the categories again.
For details about eager loading check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: Code is not exactly accurate. Please don't take it as a real C# Code.

Comment: I need your DBContext object then.